# Spring CrudRepository findAll() returning empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was using a service class for this but have removed it for a minimum reproducible example. Currently findAll() is returning an empty array, When it should be returning an array with json of EmployeeEntity from the h2. I'm still fuzzy on how spring processes data into an h2 database, so I'm guessing that could be where my problem stems from.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello2")
public class EmployeeEntityController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeEntityRepository repo;

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping()
    public Iterable<EmployeeEntity> getHello() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEES")
public class EmployeeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false, length=200)
    private String email;
    
    //public setters and getters are here, so that should be fine
```

data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO
    TBL_EMPLOYEES (first_name, last_name, email)
VALUES
    ('Lokesh', 'Gupta', 'howtodoinjava@gmail.com'),
    ('John', 'Doe', 'xyz@email.com');
```

schema.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TBL_EMPLOYEES;

CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: what happens when you execute query from ui interface do you get result?

Comment: yeah accessing localhost:8080/hello2 gives only []

Comment: No, i meant what happend when you hit sql query on h2 directly and not on spring service http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html

Comment: The table TBL_EMPLOYEES is not found. So Spring hasn't auto-configured correctly or something? Would you like me to add my pom.xml to the question?

Comment: can you check when you start your spring boot application, is there any warning logs saying table creation failed?

Comment: No warnings for table creation.

Comment: Looks like I was using the wrong h2-console url. The table is there, the rows are not populated.

Comment: you have to run code inside `data.sql` from console because there is no code you have written to insert into the database or calling any repository method

Comment: Just add SQL logs into the `application.properties` file and see what's going on, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault for not providing the project structure, but since I'm new to spring I had no idea it mattered and it wasn't brought up by anyone. The problem was my `data.sql` and `schema.sql` were outside the `resources` folder.